# Using Youtube Intent to launch a video from a defined starting point

Tags: android, youtube, android-intent

The question is easy :)

I want to start a youtube video from a defined starting position.

In a regular browser, you can achieve this by appending a #t=1m20s at the end of the url like in:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HKdsra1O20Y#t=30m10s

But If I use that URL in the Intent, the Android player is not putting the start at that point.

I'm using this to launch the activity:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HKdsra1O20Y#t=30m10s")));
```

But the video starts from the begining :(

Thanks

Comment: This was asked over a month ago, and there are no answers, so I assume there is currently no way to do this. Maybe we should submit it to Google as a feature request. Would http://code.google.com/p/android/issues be the right place to do that?

Comment: You seem to be right, using the intent it seems it isn't possible after all. But i'm open to alternatives. Maybe using the Android Media Player?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily use the Google Gdata api to call down a youtube 3gp video, then all you do is load the 3gp in a MediaPlayer instance which you can easily use its seekTo method.

Comment: Can you add a sample with the GData API nedded to get the 3gp video? :) thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524257/best-option-for-using-the-gdata-apis-on-android

Comment: True but quality is really low. You only get mobile stream which is nowhere near quality of music you get from YT intent