# How to Embed You Tube Video On Android?

Tags: android, android-widget

i am new to android.i want to make a video gallery.for that i need to take all  videos from you tube,i am able to play video of you tube but it shows me entire web site.But I don't need to show entire site,i just want to show the only the video portion.can any one help me to solve it?is there any script which i can use to solve the problem?
Thanks in Advance
Aamirkhan I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065818/using-youtube-intent-to-launch-a-video-from-a-defined-starting-point). You can get the video uri from the GData API and then start any media player.