# Unable to integrate Google Calendar API in Android app

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I've been trying for a few days to integrate Google Calendar in my Android app to little success. I've implemented the GData APIs, and used the code they've given for test purposes but keep getting a SAXParser error as below. All I need to do is to create new events in the user's Calendar.

```
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/XmlParser(28605): javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/XmlParser(28605): javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/XmlParser(28605):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParser(SAXParserFactoryImpl.java:84)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/XmlParser(28605):     at com.google.gdata.util.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:682)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/XmlParser(28605):     at com.google.gdata.util.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:576)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/XmlParser(28605):     at com.google.gdata.data.BaseEntry.parseAtom(BaseEntry.java:1015)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/XmlParser(28605):     at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.AtomDataParser.parse(AtomDataParser.java:59)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/XmlParser(28605):     at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.AtomDataParser.parse(AtomDataParser.java:39)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/XmlParser(28605):     at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.CharacterParser.parse(CharacterParser.java:100)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/XmlParser(28605):     at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.XmlInputParser.parse(XmlInputParser.java:52)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/XmlParser(28605):     at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.AtomDualParser.parse(AtomDualParser.java:66)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/XmlParser(28605):     at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.AtomDualParser.parse(AtomDualParser.java:34)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/XmlParser(28605):     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.parseResponseData(Service.java:2165)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/XmlParser(28605):     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.parseResponseData(Service.java:2098)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/XmlParser(28605):     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.insert(Service.java:1410)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/XmlParser(28605):     at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.insert(GoogleService.java:606)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/XmlParser(28605):     at <packagename>.CalendarDialog.addToCalendar(CalendarDialog.java:160)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/XmlParser(28605):     at <packagename>.CalendarDialog.onClick(CalendarDialog.java:125)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/XmlParser(28605):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2421)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/XmlParser(28605):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8869)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/XmlParser(28605):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/XmlParser(28605):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/XmlParser(28605):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/XmlParser(28605):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/XmlParser(28605):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/XmlParser(28605):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/XmlParser(28605):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/XmlParser(28605):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/XmlParser(28605):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/System.err(28605): com.google.gdata.util.ParseException: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/System.err(28605):     at com.google.gdata.util.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:708)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/System.err(28605):     at com.google.gdata.util.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:576)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/System.err(28605):     at com.google.gdata.data.BaseEntry.parseAtom(BaseEntry.java:1015)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/System.err(28605):     at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.AtomDataParser.parse(AtomDataParser.java:59)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/System.err(28605):     at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.AtomDataParser.parse(AtomDataParser.java:39)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/System.err(28605):     at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.CharacterParser.parse(CharacterParser.java:100)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/System.err(28605):     at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.XmlInputParser.parse(XmlInputParser.java:52)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/System.err(28605):     at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.AtomDualParser.parse(AtomDualParser.java:66)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/System.err(28605):     at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.AtomDualParser.parse(AtomDualParser.java:34)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/System.err(28605):     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.parseResponseData(Service.java:2165)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/System.err(28605):     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.parseResponseData(Service.java:2098)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/System.err(28605):     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.insert(Service.java:1410)
01-23 19:10:40.420: WARN/System.err(28605):     at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.insert(GoogleService.java:606)
01-23 19:10:40.430: WARN/System.err(28605):     at <packagename>.CalendarDialog.addToCalendar(CalendarDialog.java:160)
01-23 19:10:40.430: WARN/System.err(28605):     at <packagename>.CalendarDialog.onClick(CalendarDialog.java:125)
01-23 19:10:40.430: WARN/System.err(28605):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2421)
01-23 19:10:40.430: WARN/System.err(28605):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8869)
01-23 19:10:40.430: WARN/System.err(28605):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-23 19:10:40.430: WARN/System.err(28605):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-23 19:10:40.430: INFO/dalvikvm(28605): Jit: resizing JitTable from 4096 to 8192
01-23 19:10:40.440: WARN/System.err(28605):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
01-23 19:10:40.440: WARN/System.err(28605):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
01-23 19:10:40.440: WARN/System.err(28605):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 19:10:40.440: WARN/System.err(28605):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-23 19:10:40.440: WARN/System.err(28605):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-23 19:10:40.440: WARN/System.err(28605):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-23 19:10:40.440: WARN/System.err(28605):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-23 19:10:40.440: WARN/System.err(28605): Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities
01-23 19:10:40.450: WARN/System.err(28605):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParser(SAXParserFactoryImpl.java:84)
01-23 19:10:40.450: WARN/System.err(28605):     at com.google.gdata.util.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:682)
01-23 19:10:40.450: WARN/System.err(28605):     ... 25 more
```

The code I used for adding the event is:

```
void addToCalendar() throws IOException, ServiceException
    {
        CalendarService myService = new CalendarService("exampleCo-exampleApp-1");
        myService.setUserCredentials("<username>@gmail.com", "<password>");

    URL postUrl =
          new URL("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/<username>@gmail.com/private/full");
        CalendarEventEntry myEntry = new CalendarEventEntry();

        myEntry.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct("Tennis with Beth"));
        myEntry.setContent(new PlainTextConstruct("Meet for a quick lesson."));

        DateTime startTime = DateTime.parseDateTime("2011-01-26T15:00:00+05:30");
        DateTime endTime = DateTime.parseDateTime("2011-01-26T15:12:00+05:30");
        When eventTimes = new When();
        eventTimes.setStartTime(startTime);
        eventTimes.setEndTime(endTime);
        myEntry.addTime(eventTimes);

        // Send the request and receive the response:
        CalendarEventEntry insertedEntry = myService.insert(postUrl, myEntry);
}
```

Any idea what's causing the problem? Also, if anyone's got the Calendar API running, can they provide some help? Like I said, all I need is to add events (both single and recurring)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GData API won't work on your android, use google api client, from here: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Android instead.

see: [Best option for using the GData APIs on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524257/best-option-for-using-the-gdata-apis-on-android)

Comment: While I've read of this, what I find more strange than anything is that GData is now working perfectly for my app (at least the calendar bit). As you can see in the log, it's only warnings I'm receiving. The feature itself works smooth, and only a minor UI error meant I couldn't see the end product.

Answer (score 0):

See here:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9493

Answer (score 0):

you can you use GoogleApiJavaClient
see here why :
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/wiki/MigratingToGoogleApiJavaClient

look here for more resource
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/