# How to access/update google calender with Android programming?

Tags: android, calendar

I want to access/add/read etc google calender from my Android program. I have tried this,
http://www.developer.com/ws/article.php/3850276/Working-with-the-Android-Calendar.htm

But I want something else. Or, some more example and working code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can you use GoogleApiJavaClient
see here why :
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/wiki/MigratingToGoogleApiJavaClient

look here for more resource
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Google Calendar GData API](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/).

Comment: This doesnt work on Android. Also please have a look at the last part, at [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524257/best-option-for-using-the-gdata-apis-on-android  I tried the GData, it gives some parsing error.... etc.  Do you have any other working example for Android? Thanks for your time.