# Exporting contacts from Android to Gmail account

Tags: android, gmail, android-contacts, google-api-java-client

I'm a junior Android developer.  I have task to export contacts from my Android phone book to Gmail account directory `Contacts->My Contacts`, but I can't find any useful information on the Internet about Google Gmail API, so the question is how can I gain access to Gmail `My Contacts` folder to insert my contacts from the phone or when I can find information about Gmail API.

Thank you and sorry for my English.

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/ might be what you are looking for, unless you mean the proprietary Google Contacts sync adapter that is present in most/all Android phones.

Comment: as I understand,I need to divide my task in two parts: 1.authorization to my google account 2.translating my contacts into xml format and then send my xml request to the gmail server.It's correct?

Comment: Ok,could you recommend some information about authorization to web service(gmail example) for beginners,I look for that,but all information that I have found is SampleSyncAdapter app in android developer site,but this code without any explanations seems to be hard for understanding

Comment: Well, the linked API is a GData API - but that's covered well here on StackOverflow - you can check out the top answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524257/best-option-for-using-the-gdata-apis-on-android

Comment: As I understand I can use google-api-java-client to authorizing to gmail and gdata-java-client for adding contacts?I'm totally confused about my task

Comment: Isn't this part of the Android phones as they are now, GMail is tied into contacts already.  I know on my phone it already is...

Comment: In my task I have a few contacts that I need to export to gmail account,it looks like a list of available contacts,which I can checkbox and then press settings button and choose "export to gmail contacts",so after that I enter email and pass and my contacts exported to that account